# Prove or Disprove: If $A$ and $ B$ are $n \times n$ orthogonally diagonalizable matrices, then $A + B$ is orthogonally diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

So I know the properties that $A^T = A$ if its orthogonally diagonalizable and also $A=PDP^T$, But cant quite use them to prove or disprove. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you know the Spectral Theorem (for real matrices)?

Comment: Not that i know off, Just Principal Axis Theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A^T=A$ and $B^T=B$, then $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T=A+B$.

Comment: Lol I knew it was gonna be that simple, Thanks :)